# PythonAnywhere - 'phantomjs.exe' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python, phantomjs, pythonanywhere

I am hosting a project online with PythonAnywhere. One of the files use phantomjs to scrape a web page (I uploaded the Phantomjs.exe in the folder with all the other files). When I run the file which uses phantomjs I get this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'phantomjs.exe' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

So the question is, how can I add `phantomjs.exe` to the `PATH` in PythonAnywhere?

Comment: browser = webdriver.PhantomJS("Your Path")

Comment: I've already done it but it still doesn't work. All the files are in a folder called `mm` so I've set the path as `browser = webdriver.PhantomJS('phantomjs.exe')`

Comment: Please try adding the full path!

Answer (score 1):

PythonAnywhere dev here: unfortunately PhantomJS won't work on our system :-(   Maybe try using Selenium with Firefox instead?  [Here's a help page explaining how](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/selenium/).